# Is it always possible to find a polynomial representation for infinite sum series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, taylor-expansion

I am trying to find a polynomial/taylor expansion for this function:

$$f(x)=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{4}{x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{\big[\big(n+\frac{1}{2}\big)\pi\big]^4}\tanh\Bigg\{\frac{\big[\big(n+\frac{1}{2}\big)\pi\big](1+1000x)}{2}\Bigg\}$$

What are the steps I should be taking in approaching such a problem?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just out of curiosity, where did this series come from?

Comment: what is the center of your desired series? Unless you find a closed form for that monster series in $f(x)$ you're gonna have a double series as $f^{(n)}$ will always have a term $\sum \frac{\partial^n [\text{your horrid sum}]}{\partial x^n} $

Comment: Do the square brackets in $[(n+1/2)\pi]$ mean greatest integer, or are they just parentheses?

Comment: Usual ways for manipulating series like that are the Poisson summation formula and the residue theorem. $\tanh$ is not an entire function, so Taylor expansions are pretty useless, even if locally possible.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Just parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

*Short Answer:* Yes. As long as $f(x)$ is analytic in the neighborhood of $a$ you can use $f_P(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(x-a)^n}{n!}f^{(n)}(a)$.

*Long Answer:* Unless you're able to find a closed form for that series with $f$, more specifically a closed form for $D_k(x) = \frac{\partial^k}{\partial x^k} \left[ \sum \frac{(-1)^n}{[(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi]^4}\tanh \left(\frac{[(n+\frac{1}{2})\pi](1+1000x)}{2}\right) \right]$, you're always gonna have that factor of $D_k(x)$ within your series, which to me is quite ugly.

Mathematica and another CAS I tried were unable to find closed forms, so your best best would probably be to compute terms, either by hand or with a CAS.

Comment: Over $\mathbb R$ there are infinitely many times differentiable functions which are not equal with their Taylor series.